# Why was Order 66 called Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, order-66

Why did George Lucas (or whoever else) decide to call Order 66... well, Order 66?

I'm specifically looking for an out-of-universe answer. I already know that the in-universe answer is, "It came after Order 65, and before Order 67."

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6170/51379